# How to transform a Java object into a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

In a jsp I use `var accounts = ${sessionScope.allAccounts};` to get a Java list from session and transform it into a Javascript list. Then there is an error in Firebug:

> SyntaxError: illegal character ... accounts =
>   [com.ailonger.po.Account@5aced6b4,
>   com.ailonger.po.Account@4171f1ff,...

It point out that the symbol'@' which causes the problem, but I think the symbol'@' is part of the addr. of the object. I don't know where do I make mistake or how to make the transition come true.

Answer (score 0):

You could use json
This link shows how to encode java variables into json
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

To decode into a JavaScript object use JSON.parse.
An example:

```
// myJson is the encoded json string
Var myNewObj=JSON.parse(myJson)
```